# three.js - really strange behaviour with camera changes

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, orthographic

I have developed a simple `three.js` application that renders a cube, and which have several buttons to set fixed camera positions. I have a demo of my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ph0ropg7/9/

In my application I render a cube, and I can change to the top view (with the *TOP VIEW* button), and I can adjust the cube to the screen with the *SHOW ALL* button. However, I noticed three strange things:

- When I pan the cube and then I rotate it, if I press the *SHOW ALL* button, the camera orientation changes when the cube is adjusted to the screen size.
- When I set the top view with its corresponding button, the controls seems to be blocked or something like this.
- If I set the top view by clicking on the *TOP VIEW* button, and dragging before releasing the mouse left button, the controls seems to become crazy. The objects keeps vibrating in a very strange and annoying way.

I am very new to `three.js` and I cannot figure out why this three things are happening. Any help or suggestion to face any of these issues will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with point 1. You don't want the camera orientation to change? you explicitly tell it to with the line ```camera.lookAt(look_at_position);``` in ```function ShowAll()```

Comment: I've experimented a bit, but haven't come to any conclusions yet. I agree that the behaviour is strange. Maybe I just don't understand the code fully yet, but do you even need to call ```_reset_controls_after_camera_movement()``` in ```SetTopView()```? seems to work fine after removing that line. Also found an open [bug report](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11799) regarding the ```reset()``` method of OrthographicTrackballControls. Maybe this could be causing the strange behaviour...

Comment: @micnil in point 1, what I mean is the following. With the _SHOW ALL_ button I want to center the object to the screen, whatever its current orientation. With my code, the cube is "rotated" after pressing that button (when I do it as described in point 1). To be more exact, the camera is rotated, not the cube.

Comment: @Rabbid76 your solution adjusts the cube to the screen with the _SHOW ALL_ button, but it always have the same orientation. That is not what I am looking for. I would like to adjust the cube to the screen, but preserving the orientation given by the user with the controls. I mean, to move and zoom it to center it in the screen, but with no rotation.

Comment: I could not reproduce #3 of the "three strange things" while using the Chrome browser. What browser did you use to view the vibrating objects?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome version 59.0.3071.115.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the OrthographicTrackballControls [source](https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrthographicTrackballControls.js) and noticed that it uses the cameras `lookAt` method when performing a reset. The `lookAt` method will align the camera with its `up` vector. So what you need to do is remove the call to `camera.lookAt(look_at_position);` in your ShowAll & ShowTop functions and add `controls.up0.copy(camera.up);` in your `_reset_controls_after_camera_movement` method. The control will now have the correct up vector and can perform the lookat for you.

here's a [modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph0ropg7/24/)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!